# NodeJS - Why does adding quotes to "node" change the behavior of the resulting program?

Tags: node.js, windows

Consider the following tiny JavaScript program:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const inquirer = require('inquirer');

async function foo() {
  const response = await inquirer.prompt({
    type: "confirm",
    name: "foo",
    message: "Do you want to foo?",
    default: true,
  });

  console.log(response.foo);
}

foo();
```

All this program does is ask the end-user a question using the [Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/) library.

However, using a standard Git Bash terminal (on Windows), invoking it with and without quotes changes the behavior of the program, as demonstrated by the following screenshot:

[image: Git Bash]

When quotes are put around node, it causes the question to get duplicated in the terminal, which makes the program look like it is bugging out.

1. Why does adding quotes to "node" change the behavior of the program?
2. Is there some kind of fix that I can include in my JavaScript code to work around this problem?

Comment: Node (and browsers) color-codes logged expressions depending on what type they are, which is probably semi-related to whatever's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

[image: picture of terminal without strange behaviour]

I don't think it is your program.

---

It looks to me like the problem is just with refreshing the line.  To make the problem smaller, try the same experiment with this program I found:

```
var util = require('util');
var x = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  process.stdout.write('hello: ' + x + '\r');
  x++;
}, 1000);
```

source: https://gist.github.com/markcode/a8b1bfa545bb701daa2c

This program has no colours, so if it happens, it is just because putting "node" in quotes makes it so it can't `\r` without `\n`

If replace `main` with the above program, you and put it in quotes, and see this, then you are closer

```
$ "node" main.js
hello: 1
hello: 2
hello: 3
```

Please let me know the answer if you work it out.. really interesting.

---

ok I got one more idea from quickly browsing their code and seeing where they have an if that adds a `\n` - it's kind of long shot but try to run this program with and without quotes around node

```
const readline = require('readline');
const cliWidth = require('cli-width');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

console.log(cliWidth({
  defaultWidth: 80,
  output: rl.output,
}));

process.exit(0);
```

it has to be saved in that project directory because `cli-width` as a project dependency.

I am wondering if that program gives you `0` when you use the quotes, and that causes this to happen:

```
    if (rawPromptLine.length % width === 0) {
      content += '\n';
    }
```

(from https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/blob/caefb11e7970bbec454be979e6f5d24e40d1b0bb/packages/core/lib/screen-manager.js)

Comment: 0h the `n` that I put in as an argument.. that's an accident... I just retried.. it's got nothing to do with anything.. so don't let the `n` after `main.js` throw you off

Comment: Also what do you get for `"node" --version` and `node --version`?

Comment: 1) It doesn't look like you are using Git Bash for Windows. 2) I tried out that program, and putting node in quotes does not change the behavior of the program.

Comment: Yeah - I am using just normal bash.  That's why I thought it must be related to the environment... but I see now that it is more complicated than that.. something in this library behaves funny in this one case with git bash!

Comment: I've added one more long shot idea before I have to borrow a friend's windows computer to try it. Please take a look at my update if you have a sec